# I want my program to stop accepting input from console when I type STOP in console C++ Program

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, stdin, fgets

I am making a C++ program which accepts input from user (even \n) is required but the program should stop when I type STOP, so can anyone help me out.  Earlier I was using getline but that also got some issue like when I enter \n two (hit enter two times) it stops the whole code.

So can anyone guide me what to do, I want to capture whole input until user types STOP in console.

Thank you.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        cout<<"Main Started\n";
        char array[10];
        string str;
    
        while(fgets(array,sizeof(array),stdin))
        {
            str = (string) array;
            if(str=="STOP")  // This line is not getting executed. Also tried strcmp but of no use
                break;
           
        }
    
        cout<<"\nMain Ended\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `STOP` and enter? You could use `std::cin >> input; if (input == "STOP")`

Comment: The user should type STOP in console and then press enter. After that only the program should stop taking input.

Comment: yes I tried cin >> input , but the problem is cin doesn't capture spaces between text.

Comment: Suppose I am storing some names so in that case the first name and surname won;t have GAP between them as cin doesn't store spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets()` includes `'\n'` in the output, if the read is terminated by <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, so you need to check for that, eg:

```cpp
while (fgets(array, sizeof(array), stdin) != NULL)
{
    str = array;
    if (str == "STOP" || str == "STOP\n")
        break;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
while (fgets(array, sizeof(array), stdin) != NULL)
{
    if (strcmp(str, "STOP") == 0 || strcmp(str, "STOP\n") == 0)
        break;
}
```

`std::getline()` (and `std::istream::getline()`), on the other hand, do not include the terminating `'\n'` in the output:

```cpp
while (getline(cin, str))
{
    if (str == "STOP")
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my time. Thanks a ton. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use getline:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Main Started\n";
    std::string str;

    while(std::getline(std::cin, str)) {
        if(str == "STOP")  
            break;
    }

    std::cout << "\nMain Ended\n";
    return 0;
}
```

or `operator>>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Main Started\n";
    std::string str;

    while(std::cin >> str) {
        if(str == "STOP")  
            break;
    }

    std::cout << "\nMain Ended\n";
    return 0;
}
```